# Capturing echo to stdout from Vim

Tags: vim

I have a vim script that I am sourcing with `--cmd "source path/to/file.vim"`. The full command is a bit longer and the final command is to quit vim like so.

```
vim --cmd 'source path/to/file1.vim' [... source other files] --cmd ':q'
```

In these files I am doing some processing that outputs messages to vim with `echomsg`. I want to capture these messages to `stdout`.

The problem is some of this processing requires sleeping for a bit with `sleep`. However doing a `sleep` causes vim to redraw the screen. As a result messages that were echoed initially are partially cleared in this screen redraw.

Once I quit Vim I can see that the messages were output in sequence correctly in the shell, but the intermittent redrawing messed up the display.

One workaround I came up with is to use `writefile` to write the messages to a file instead of using stdout, but then I loose the ability to show progress.

> Is there a better way to capture echo'ed messages to stdout from a vimscript? I would like to display the messages as they occur, as these are progress messages.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect ex command to STDOUT in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739300/redirect-ex-command-to-stdout-in-vim)

Comment: Also see [Vim execute a command and send out buffer over stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17266098).

Comment: Both these are good answers, but don't solve the issue. For 1. I can't use `-s`, because of the vimrc suppression. 2. Piping won't work as it runs after vim exits. I want the screen to update as the messages are sent, to show progress. The main issue is `sleep` triggers redraws which clears out the echo messages sent before.

Comment: So you want to run Vim automated inside a batch job, but still show output while it's running? That half-interactive mode is quite far from the usual use cases, no wonder it works poorly...

Comment: @IngoKarkat more or less. :) Is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked the `'lazyredraw'` option? Maybe together with `:redraw` you can echo the messages correctly.

Comment: `lazyredraw` sounds useful. I ended up writing to a buffer to display progress and redirecting that to a file on close. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A later redraw may make the message disappear, so to avoid that you may force a `redraw`, e.g.:

```
:new | redraw | echo "there is a new window"
```

Or check `lazyredraw` instead as per comments.

To capture echo (or other messages) to the standard output, you can use `redir` command, e.g.:

```
$ ex +"redir>>/dev/stdout | echomsg 'foo' | redir END" -scq!
foo
```

If you're interested in messages about which files are sourced, use `-V` parameter, so your message (`echomsg`) would be displayed as well without any need for redirect, e.g.:

```
$ ex -V +"echomsg 'foo'" -scq!
...
Searching for "vimfiles/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for ".vim/after/plugin/**/*.vim" 
foo
```